# Filtering an object by multiple arguments(inputs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a lot of inputs, after which my object is supposed to filter, I can hardcode it, but there is probably a smarter way to do it

Filter state :

```
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState<FiltersType>({
    login: "",
    name: "",
    surrname: "",
  });
```

Example data:

```
const data: UserRow[] = [
 
  {
    key: "1",
    login: "John@gmail.com",
    name: "John",
    surrname: "Smith",
    role: ["user"],
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    login: "Andrew@gmail.com",
    name: "Andrew",
    surrname: "Johnson",
    role: ["user"],
  },

];
```

```
data.filter((e) => {
              if (
                (!filters.name || e.name.includes(filters.name)) &&
                (!filters.surrname || e.surrname.includes(filters.surrname)) &&
                (!e.login ||
                  e.login.toLowerCase().includes(filters.login.toLowerCase()))
              ) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            })
```

For example, it can be done like this, but as you can see it looks bad and scales poorly when adding new fields, I tried to simplify it using "Object.entries()", but ultimately failed :(. What is the best pattern for such a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the name and surname also be lowercase?

Comment: By the way, sorry, but shouldn't it be `surname`, not `surrname`? :(

Comment: Can you include an objective output? You're showing code that's hard to follow, I'm not quite sure what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: It should be surname, as for lowecase I wrote it quickly now on stackoverflow, and forgot to add to the rest, it is not relevant as something XD.

Comment: code : Imagine you have a table with data, above the table you have 3 inputs that filter the data when entered.

E.g. for input {login: "John", name : "John", surname: "Smith",} the first object will be returned. 

On the other hand, for input {login: "John", name : "John", surname: "Johnson",} nothing will be returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (logical `OR` for all the conditions) or [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (logical `AND` for all the conditions) in combination with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    login: "John@gmail.com",
    name: "John",
    surrname: "Smith",
    role: ["user"],
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    login: "Andrew@gmail.com",
    name: "Andrew",
    surrname: "Johnson",
    role: ["user"],
  },
];

const filter = {
  login: "",
  name: "",
  surrname: "",
};
const filters = Object.entries(filter);
const filtered = data.filter((user) =>
  filters.some(
    ([key, value]) =>
      user[key] && user[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value)
  )
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Use `some()` if you want to include the result if any of the filter conditions is met and use `every()` if you want to only include a result if all filter conditions are met.

> The above will work for simple filters. You can however extend the solution using `typeof()` or `Array.isArray()` function etc. to process different types like arrays, nested objects etc. accordingly.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, I finally managed to solve the problem with the following code

'''
filters.every(
                ([key, value]) =>
                  !value ||
                  (value && e[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value))
              );
'''